# Adding an `animation` declaration messes up the z-indexes, kind of

Tags: css, overflow, css-animations, z-index

Using Bootstrap's native classes, I have a list of `.list-group-item` elements, in which there are some clickable options, shown as dropdowns in the `.dropdown-menu`. By default this works fine, even when the dropdown of one `.list-group-item` element goes over the one below it.

What I've added then, is an `animation` declaration that fades in the `.list-group-item`s by using `@keyframes` animation going from `opacity:0` to `opacity:1`. And as a side-effect of that, every `.list-group-item` element goes visually over the dropdown menu from the previous one.

(there aren't actually any `z-index` declarations involved, I've only used that term in the title to illustrate the manifestation of the issue)

I am wondering if there is some kind of workaround for this overflowing issue that would allow me to keep the fade-in animation for the elements?

An example can be seen on the following fiddle (there is no javascript involved or included there as it is not necesarry, so both of the dropdowns are just declared as open in the HTML code to illustrate the situation):

https://jsfiddle.net/o8ysz4qp/2/

HTML:

```
<div class="list-group-item fade-in">
  <div class="pull-right dropdown open">
    <button class="btn btn-primary">
      &darr;
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>

<div class="list-group-item fade-in">
  <div class="pull-right dropdown open">
    <button class="btn btn-primary">
      &darr;
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.fade-in {
  opacity: 0; 
  animation:fade-in .5s ease; 
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay:1s;
}
@keyframes fade-in {
  from { opacity:0; }
  to { opacity:1; }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problems is that when the opacity is not 1 it creates a new stacking context (*See [The stacking context - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context)*)

A solution is to add a `z-index` (*since it becomes usable after the opacity change*) and reverse their value (the last one has the lowest `z-index` etc)

Something like (*assuming they are siblings*)

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.list-group-item:nth-last-child(1){z-index:1}
.list-group-item:nth-last-child(2){z-index:2}
.list-group-item:nth-last-child(3){z-index:3}
.list-group-item:nth-last-child(4){z-index:4}
.list-group-item:nth-last-child(5){z-index:5}
.list-group-item:nth-last-child(6){z-index:6}
.list-group-item:nth-last-child(7){z-index:7}

.fade-in {
  opacity: 0; 
  animation:fade-in .5s ease; 
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay:1s;
}
@keyframes fade-in {
  from { opacity:0; }
  to { opacity:1; }
}
```

```html
<div class="list-group-item fade-in">
  <div class="pull-right dropdown open">
    <button class="btn btn-primary">
      &darr;
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>
<div class="list-group-item fade-in">
  <div class="pull-right dropdown open">
    <button class="btn btn-primary">
      &darr;
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yup! And just to make add one more remark, I guess, (because my page wasn't actually made of `list-group-item` divs, but table rows), a `position:relative` declaration is required.

Comment: Btw I have to wait 23 hours to give you the 200 point bounty reward, so like... I don't know... Stackoverflow stuff... I thought you'd get it automatically when I accept your answer, i don't know what this means now, that I can just decide to not give it to you just because I'm a dick? Bleh...

Comment: @ImNotMike You don't need to award the bounty prematurely. Since you accepted the answer, it will be automatically awarded after 7 days (8 with the grace period). See http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty

Comment: @ImNotMike also keep in mind that the example code i gave deals with only 7 sibling groups. You should add more rules to handle more rows (*if that is your case*)

Answer (score 2):

As Gaby explained, animating `opacity` establishes a stacking context.

So instead of animating the opacity on each `.list-group-item`, you should place them all in a container and animate `opacity` there.

```css
@import 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css';
body {
  opacity: 0; 
  animation: fade-in 2s ease; 
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes fade-in {
  from { opacity:0; }
  to { opacity:1; }
}
```

```html
<div class="list-group-item fade-in">
  <div class="pull-right dropdown open">
    <button class="btn btn-primary">
      &darr;
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>
<div class="list-group-item fade-in">
  <div class="pull-right dropdown open">
    <button class="btn btn-primary">
      &darr;
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>
```